# How to read all parquet files from a folder in s3 to pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, parquet

How can I read all the parquet files in a folder (written by Spark), into a `pandas` `DataFrame` using Python 3.x? Preferably without `pyarrow` due to version conflicts.

Folder contains parquet files with pattern `part-*.parquet` and a `_SUCCESS` file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `s3fs` to list files and `dask` to read the files like so:

```python
import s3fs
import dask.dataframe as dd

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

def get_files(input_folder):
    files = s3.ls(input_folder)
    files = ['s3://' + str(file) for file in files if not str(file).endswith('_SUCCESS')]
    return files

def read_files(input_folder):
    files = get_files(input_folder)
    df = dd.read_parquet(files)
    return df

df = read_files(input_folder)
```